# How to create a separate view model for a contentview in Xamarin forms having prism?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Problem Statement
I want to create a contentview user control having its own view model that can be used in multiple content pages.

Issue in below implementation
I have extended my App.xaml.cs as mentioned below. But once the navigation works from the contentpage having contentview user control but if I navigate again to that page, the navigation doesn't work. Just to add to it, view.Parent also comes out to be null in the below code.

Please help.

```
using OEP.Views;
using Prism;
using Prism.Common;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Prism.Unity;
using Unity.Resolution;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace OEP
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NewOrderPage");
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
            //await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("HomePage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ForgotPasswordPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<HomePage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CustomerDetailsPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NewOrderPage>();
            //Container.Resolve<HomePageCustomersUserControl>("Customers");
            //containerRegistry.Register<HomePageCustomersUserControl, HomePageCustomersUserControlViewModel>();
            //ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<HomePageCustomersUserControl>(() => Container.Resolve<HomePageCustomersUserControlViewModel>());
        }

        protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
        {
            ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((view, type) =>
            {
                Page page = null;
                switch (view)
                {
                    case Page page1:
                        page = page1;
                        break;
                    case Element customView:
                        page = GetPageFromElement(customView);
                        // Existing parameter with the Page
                        break;
                }

                var navService = CreateNavigationService(page);
                ParameterOverrides overrides = new ParameterOverrides
                {
                        { "navigationService", navService }
                };
                return Container.GetContainer().Resolve(type, type.GetType().Name, overrides);

            });
        }

        // Currently exists
        protected INavigationService CreateNavigationService(Page page)
        {
            var navigationService = NavigationService;
            ((IPageAware)navigationService).Page = page;
            return navigationService;
        }

        protected INavigationService CreateNavigationService(object view)
        {
            switch (view)
            {
                case Page page:
                    return CreateNavigationService(page);
                case Element element:
                    var parentPage = GetPageFromElement(element);
                    if (parentPage == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return CreateNavigationService(parentPage);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        private Page GetPageFromElement(Element view)
        {
            switch (view.Parent)
            {
                case Page page:
                    return page;
                case null:
                    return null;
                default:
                    return GetPageFromElement(view.Parent);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is supported in Prism 7.1. The following is taken directly from the Prism Unit Tests. If you're following the naming convention you actually do not need to register anything, you simply need to set ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView with a reference to the parent page.

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Prism.DI.Forms.Tests.Mocks.Views.PartialView">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                x:Name="navigateButton" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>

<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prism.DI.Forms.Tests.Mocks.Views"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    xmlns:converters="using:Prism.Forms.Tests.Mocks.Converters"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    x:Name="xamlViewMock"
    x:Class="Prism.DI.Forms.Tests.Mocks.Views.XamlViewMock">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <prism:ContainerProvider x:TypeArguments="converters:MockValueConverter" x:Key="mockValueConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:PartialView mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference xamlViewMock}" />
        <Entry x:Name="testEntry"
        Text="{Binding Test,Converter={StaticResource mockValueConverter}}" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

- [Partial View](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DI.Forms.Tests/Mocks/Views/XamlViewMock.xaml)
- [Consuming Page](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DI.Forms.Tests/Mocks/Views/PartialView.xaml)

In the event you need to follow some custom Naming scheme you simply need to call:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MyView, SomeViewModel>();
```

### UPDATE

Prism 8 will be introducing support for Region Navigation. As a result the "Partial Views" introduced in Prism 7.1 will be removed. You will need migrate to use Regions. This is very easy to do, though there will be some fundamental differences with how to pass parameters into regions.

Comment: I think the links for Partial View and Consuming Page are swapped

Comment: Is there a sample project for this? I'm not able to run the source for Prism-master, and it seems to be a mocked example anyway. I'm trying to get a Xamarin app with partialviews and their own commands working. I'm able to set the viewmodel properly but my commands are not getting called.

Comment: I've gotten it working. It turns out my button was covered by an invisible view! 

Note that if you don't have your ContentViews in your Views folder, then Prism won't know where to look (and why would you if they're partialviews and not pages?). So you need to use `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MyView, SomeViewModel>();` as Dan Siegel suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to define new `ViewModel` for `ContentView`'s. You just need to use `AutowirePartialView` property in `Page` where you are using `ContentView`. Like this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <local:CardViewTemplatePage prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="true"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your `ContentView` should bind fields like this

```
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Label TextColor="Denim" Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <Label TextColor="DimGray" Text="{Binding Description}" />
</StackLayout>
```